# Disable cascade deletion with EF code first doesn't work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have the following classes and I've created the database tables using EF Code-first. However, I found the deletion cascade is on and tried to remove it.

```
public class Category
{
    [Key, DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And I have added the following code in the DbContext class.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Use singular table names
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Events)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CategoryId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

However, the generated migration code generate two `AddForeignKey` states with one with cascadeDeletion and another one without it.

```
AddForeignKey("dbo.Event", "CategoryId", "dbo.Category", "Id");
AddForeignKey("dbo.Event", "CategoryId", "dbo.Category", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
CreateIndex("dbo.Event", "CategoryId");
CreateIndex("dbo.Event", "CategoryId");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.WithRequired()` call you use [configures the relationship to be optional:required **without** a navigation property on the other side of the relationship](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696502%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) so that results in one `AddForeignKey` call.

Then you have a `Category` navigation property that hasn't been configured in the FluentAPI so EF generates another `AddForeignKey` call that uses the default configuration.

Try using the override of `WithRequired` that [configures the relationship to be optional:required **with** a navigation property on the other side of the relationship](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671235%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Events)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Category)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CategoryId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```